# Sieve of Eratosthenes will not sieve Prime Numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, sieve-of-eratosthenes

For an assignment I am doing for one of my classes, we have to implement a Sieve of Eratosthenes. I have tried seven times to get a code that works and have tried incorporating numerous solutions I've researched. I finally have one that will output numbers.  Unfortunately, it prints both composite and prime numbers, and doesn't print 2.

My code is as follows:

```
public class EratosthenesSieveAttempt6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int limit;

        System.out.print("Please enter the highest number to check "
                + "(number must be greater than 2): ");

        limit = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (limit <= 2){
          System.out.println("Error - number must be greater than 2.");
          System.out.println("Please enter the highest number to check: ");
          limit = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        boolean[] numbers = new boolean[limit + 1];
        int newPrime = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < limit + 1; i++){
          numbers[i] = true;       
        }

        for(int j = 1; j < limit + 1; j++) {
          if (j % 2 == 0) {
           numbers[j] = false;   
           }

        for(int k = j + 1; k < limit + 1; k++) {
           if(numbers[k] == true){
             j = k;

        System.out.println(k);
               }
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

I'm suspecting that there is a problem with my loops. I fixed the `i` and `j` variables for my first two loops so that it would print out from 2 onward, the problem seems to be that it's not marking the composite numbers as false after I've initialized the array to `true`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: this is not eratosthenes approach and doesn't work , you have to make a variables multiplications `false` in the list

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi which variables?  Do I have to start out with them being all flagged false?  Do I need to rewrite the code entirely?

Comment: Please fix indentations to make code **readable**!!

Comment: Your code checks if numbers can be divided by 2 or not. That is just not enough, you should check with 3, (4), 5, (6), 7, etc. So you need nested loops. The parenthesed numbers can be checked, but that is not necessary (you can recognize that in your array: if something is false already, it does not need further checking, its multiplies have been handled already). Also, when you check if numbers are divisible by n, you should start checking from n+1 (e.g. 3 is divisible with 3, but it is a prime, while 6, 9, 12, etc. are not). In fact, the real sieve does not divide, it multiplies.

Comment: look you know `2` is prime , then it's multiplications is not prime ` 4 , 6 , 8 , 10 , 12 , 14 , ... ` after you flagged these as `false` , you must go to the next number `3` is prime so ` 6 , 9 , 12 , 15 , ... ` are not prime and must be flagged , then the next number will be `5` and so on , you have to do this with `i` and `j` variables

Comment: see my solution , you can find the implemented code

Comment: @tevemadar great comment, except, the real sieve does not multiply either, it sums (repeatedly). `primes = {2} U ({3,4,...} \ U { {p,p+p,...} for p in primes })`.

Comment: My answer was **true** and you **unmarked** it , and i don't know who downvoted it , you've done the wrong thing , it was not moral ! i'll remember your name

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi: ?  I have it both checked and uprated on mine.  I promise you I haven't touched it since I marked your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes I wrote the other day:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public static BitSet composite(int max) {
    BitSet composite = new BitSet(max);
    max = composite.size();
    for (int i = 4; i < max; i += 2) composite.set(i, true);
    for (int i = 9; i < max; i += 6) composite.set(i, true);
    int p = 5;
    while (p*p < max) {
        if (!composite.get(p)) {
            for (int i = p*p; i < max; i += p*2) composite.set(i, true);
        }
        p += 2;
        if (p*p >= max) break;
        if (!composite.get(p)) {
            for (int i = p*p; i < max; i += p*2) composite.set(i, true);
        }
        p += 4;
    }
    return composite;
}
```

Notes:

- BitSet allocates 64-bit words, so the size may be larger than you requested (for example, if you ask it to go up to 1000, it will go up to 1024; that's the reason for `max = composite.size()` near the top)
- Gets the 2's, 3's out of the way explicitly, and then
- Relies on the fact that all primes larger than 3 are congruent to either 1 or 5 mod 6; this is the reason the final loop alternates between adding 2 and 4

It returns a `BitSet` that tells you which numbers are composite. One way to extract just the primes from it would be:

```
public static int[] primes(BitSet composite) {
    int size = composite.size() - 2 - composite.cardinality();
    int[] primes = new int[size];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < composite.size(); i++) {
        if (!composite.get(i)) primes[index++] = i;
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that BitSet was a class in Java!  That is quite helpful to know.  I can follow some of this; are `.size()` and `.cardinality()` both methods of that class?

Comment: @KMN Yes. See the [`BitSet` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) for more information.